# To Add Edit icon button on each row in javascript for devextreme datagrid

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, model-view-controller, devextreme

I tried to bind grid data dynamically, in that data comes from the controller and want to add an edit icon button for each row of the grid through javascript. In Javascript, for columns, I have no existing columns because columns are directly bound through the controller. So how to do it? My Ajax call is like this

```
$.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "/controllername/method",
            data: {
                
            },
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                $('#gridContainer').dxDataGrid({
                    dataSource: JSON.parse(data),
                    keyExpr: 'ID',
                    allowColumnReordering: true,
                    allowColumnResizing: true,
                    allowHeaderFiltering: true,
                    allowSearch: true,
                    columnAutoWidth: true,
                    showBorders: true,
                    allowExportSelectedData: true,
                    selection: {
                        mode: 'multiple',
                        allowSelectAll: true,
                        showCheckBoxesMode: 'always'
                    },
                    scrolling: {
                        mode: "standard",
                        ScrollByContent: true,
                        scrollByThumb: true
                    },
                    paging: {
                        pageSize: 20,
                    },
                    pager: {
                        visible: true,
                        showInfo: true,
                        showNavigationButtons: true
                    },
                    filterRow: {
                        visible: true,
                        applyFilter: 'auto'
                    },
                    filterPanel: {
                        visible: true
                    },
                    searchPanel: {
                        visible: true,
                        highlightCaseSensitive: true,
                        width: 240
                    },
                    columnChooser: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    headerFilter: {
                        visible: true
                    },
                    export: {
                        enabled: true,
                        allowExportSelectedData: true
                    },
                    grouping: {
                        autoExpandAll: true
                    },
                    groupPanel: {
                        visible: true,
                        emptyPanelText: 'Drag a column header here to group by that column'
                    },
                    editing: {
                        mode: 'row'
                    },
                    },

                    onContentReady: functonname,
                    selection: {
                        mode: "multiple"
                    },

                });
            }
        });
```

My grid data is loaded. I want to add an Action column with each row having an edit icon button.